# android fragment 3 pages

Tags: java, android, fragment

Well I am new to Android and I am trying to make a 3 pages swipe app. I created a new project from eclipse and selected project with fixed tabs and scrollable pages. I have deleted the tabs because I want an app only with scrollable pages. Here's the code

the MainActivity Class

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
            public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {


SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final int PAGE_COUNT=3;

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.

    }
}




/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null; 
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(getBaseContext(), first.class.getName());
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(getBaseContext(), second.class.getName());
            break;              
        case 2:
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class.getName());
            break;          }
    return fragment;    
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }
    public class good  extends Fragment{

    }


    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And this is one fragment first.java

```
     public class first extends FragmentActivity{


  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // here you can load whatever layout you want for your fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prva, container, false);
        return v;
  }}
```

Errors I got:

```
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828): android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.swipe.MainActivity$SectionsPagerAdapter$good: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:413)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:377)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at com.example.swipe.MainActivity$SectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(MainActivity.java:91)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:97)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:982)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15473)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5056)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15473)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15473)
10-30 14:46:20.355: E/AndroidRuntime(7828):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5056)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct..
I think that your problem is related to the build path and libs android-support-v4.jar
Sometime ( for me in eclipse ) if you have a jar in libs folder the project compile, but if you not include correct it in the build path the project crash at run time.

Can you check if in Properties - java build path - Order and export - The android-support-v4.jar must be present checked and up

Comment: Good!!!
Ok this problem is one step back...you must add the android-suport-v4.jar lib to the build path, go to the previous tab "Libraries" in the screenshot, then click on add and search in your project root the folder named lib or libs, into this folder you must find the android-support-v4.jar, click on it and add to the build path.

Next step you can do what i've explained in the previous comment.